# rendering nvd3-line-chart inside angular-ui tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, nvd3.js, redraw

I am trying to render a linechart using https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives inside a angular-ui tab.

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="tab1">
    <nvd3-line-chart data="exampleData"></nvd3-line-chart>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="tab2">
    <nvd3-line-chart data="exampleData2"></nvd3-line-chart>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

The first tab renders the graph, however when I select the second tab, the graph is not rendered.
As soon as I resize the window, the graph appears as it is re-rendered by the directive on window.resize.

How can I get the graph in tab B to render automatically?

(I already tried triggering a window resize event on tab change. It felt very dirty and didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved issue by refreshing all charts:

```
<tab select="refreshCharts()">
```

and then

```
$scope.refreshCharts = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < nv.graphs.length; i++) {
            nv.graphs[i].update();
        }
    };
```

Probably it's a good idea to pass charts to update as arguments to avoid unnecessary redraws.

Comment: If anyone come across this issue where the function is not called even after selecting the tab, you can use ng-click="refreshCharts()" also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting `objectequality="true"` ?

Please see this thread: https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/issues/177